# Is shoulda destroying my backtraces?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, shoulda, backtrace

I have a test more or less like this:

```
class FormDefinitionTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  context "a form_definition" do
    setup do
      @definition = SeedData.form_definition
      # ...
```

I've purposely added a

```
raise "blah"
```

somewhere down the road and I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: blah
test/unit/form_definition_test.rb:79:in `__bind_1290079321_362430'
```

when I should be getting something along:

```
/Users/pupeno/projectx/db/seed/sheet_definitions.rb:17:in `sheet_definition': blah (RuntimeError)
    from /Users/pupeno/projectx/db/seed/form_definitions.rb:4:in `form_definition'
    from /Users/pupeno/projectx/test/unit/form_definition_test.rb:79
```

Any ideas what is sanitizing/destroying my backtraces? My suspicious is shoulda because the when the exception happens inside a setup or should is whet it happens.

This is a Rails 3 project, in case that's important.

Comment: why do this raise if you want raise some exception ? If it's a test, it's not the format to do.

Comment: @shingara I'm doing that raise just to see how it looks like. What's really happen is that I'm getting an exception from somewhere, another exception, but I can't find where since something is hiding most of the backtrace.

Comment: All stacktrace you report are from your "raise blah". So I don't understand your really problem

Comment: @shingara: my problem is that the stack trace when the error occurs inside a method called from setup or should, doesn't contain all the frames up to the raise itself. form_definition_test.rb:79 doesn't raise "blah", it's raised by a method called by another method call by it, as you can see in the second stack trace.

Comment: @J. Pablo Fernandez: If you're adding a `raise "blah"` in order to post a minimal (reproducible) example, we would appreciate it if you could post a minimal example that we can run ourselves (without having to add any code ourselves) to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm having this problem too.  Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: The problem he is trying to report is that shoulda seems to somehow swallow the exceptions raised along the test, thus hidding their stack trace. I am having the same problem.

Comment: maybe the backtrace silencers are messing with you. Read the comment in config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb. I usually remove all the cleaners. I can live with long backtraces.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the shoulda method `#context` is generating code for you. for each `#should` block it generates a completely separate test for you so e.g.

```
class FormDefinitionTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  context "a form_definition" do
    setup do
      @definition = SeedData.form_definition
    end

    should "verify some condition" do
      assert something
    end

    should "verify some other condition" do
      assert something_else
    end
  end
end
```

Then `#should` will generate two completely independent tests (for the two invocations of `#should`), one that executes

```
      @definition = SeedData.form_definition
      assert something
```

and another one that executes

```
      @definition = SeedData.form_definition
      assert something_else
```

It is worth noting that it does **not** generate one single test executing all three steps in a sequence.

These generated blocks of codes have method names like `_bind_` something and the generated test have name that is a concatenation of all names of the contexts traversed to the `should` block plus the string provided by the should block (prefixed with "should "). There is [another example in the documentation for shoulda-context](http://rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/shoulda-context/master/frames).

Answer (score 0):

I think this will give you the backtrace that you want. I haven't tested it, but it should work:

```
def exclude_backtrace_from_location(location)
  begin
    yeild
  rescue => e
    puts "Error of type #{e.class} with message: #{e.to_s}.\nBacktrace:"
    back=e.backtrace
    back.delete_if {|b| b~=/\A#{location}.+/}
    puts back
  end
end

exclude_backrace_from_location("test/unit") do
  #some shoulda code that raises...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked `config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb`? That is the entry point to customize that behavior. With `Rails.backtrace_cleaner.remove_silencers!` you can cleanup the silencers stack.

More informations about `ActiveSupport::BacktraceCleaner` can be found [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/BacktraceCleaner.html).